# Gradle + Spring Boot Error: Failed to bind properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I am moving from Maven to Gradle and a Spring boot service fails to come up when run via the Gradle generated jar file. The app runs fine as a Spring app or when run as a jar generated through maven.
I have a feeling we are missing some dependency in Gradle but not able to place a finger on it. Appreciate if someone can point out what I am missing.

Error:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15 03:37:23 UTC","message":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory'
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Could not bind properties to 'ServerProperties' : prefix=server, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'server.error.include-stacktrace' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorProperties$IncludeAttribute","thread":"main","logLevel":"WARN","fileName":"AbstractApplicationContext.java","line":591,"serviceCode":"SMPL-JAVA-MS"}
{"timestamp":"2021-09-15 03:37:23 UTC","message":"\n\nError starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.","thread":"main","logLevel":"INFO","fileName":"ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java","line":136,"serviceCode":"SMPL-JAVA-MS"}
```

Gradle dependencies

```
  implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.4.2'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:+'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:+'
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:+'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:+'
  implementation 'org.opensaml:opensaml:2.5.1-1'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:+'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:+'
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
  runtimeOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
  runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:+'
  runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:+'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:+'
```

pox.xml

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <groupId>***</groupId>
  <artifactId>***</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>***</name>
  <description>***</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>16</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.20</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- swagger UI at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Web Client for accessing external requests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the maven dependencies so that we can try with the same?

Comment: Without the `pom.xml` and the full `build.gradle` this will be impossible to answer. One thing I notice is the `+` for the version, those shouldn't be there and that you have `spring-boot-starter-test` both as a test and implementation dependency (that should be only for test).

Comment: @Supritam I have updated my Q with pom.xml contents. And removing the `spring-boot-starter-test` duplicate entry did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. Turned out to be a deprecated property in my `application.properties` file. This needed to go:

```
server.error.include-stacktrace=ON_TRACE_PARAM
```